# How to retrieve data which is not in another table using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to know the records which is not in `table2`.

Here my query,

```
select 
    jj.ItemID,
    jj.ItemLookupCode
FROM 
    [JC_ItemDailySalesParent] jj
left join [F_ItemDailySalesParent] ff
on jj.ItemID != ff.ItemID 
    and year(ff.time)='2017'
    and month(ff.time)='3' 
    and day(ff.time)='1'
    and ff.StoreID='1400'
where year(jj.time)='2017' 
    and month(jj.time)='3' 
    and day(jj.time)='1' 
    and jj.StoreID='1400'
```

When I do count of [JC_ItemDailySalesParent] is **217**
and the count of [F_ItemDailySalesParent] is **210**.

```
select 
    storeid,
    count(Storeid)
from [JC_ItemDailySalesParent]
where year(time)='2017' and month(time)='3' and day(time)='1'
group by StoreID

select 
    storeid,
    count(Storeid)
from [F_ItemDailySalesParent]
where year(time)='2017' and month(time)='3' and day(time)='1'
group by StoreID
```

**Result of count**

```
StoreID count
1001     217
1201     3140
1302     5635
1400     5422
2001     5541
2400     4565

StoreID count
1001     210  //want to know these missing 7 records from above table
1201     3075
1302     5607
1400     5394
2001     5469
2400     4542
```

Comment: You should really use date criteria properly, `ff.time >= '20170301 and ff.time < '20170302'` instead of functions that prevent indexes being used

Comment: @Jamesz leave it that one. I want to get that record. can you help for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery here, instead of joining two tables:

```
SELECT
    jj.ItemID,
    jj.ItemLookupCode
FROM 
    [JC_ItemDailySalesParent] jj
WHERE
    jj.ItemID NOT IN (
        SELECT ff.ItemID FROM [F_ItemDailySalesParent] ff
        WHERE year(ff.time)='2017'
            AND month(ff.time)='3' 
            AND day(ff.time)='1'
            AND ff.StoreID='1400')
    AND year(jj.time)='2017' 
    AND month(jj.time)='3' 
    AND day(jj.time)='1' 
    AND jj.StoreID='1400'
```

And you probably should use the `BETWEEN` function or compare operations instead of datetime functions, as @JamesZ said.